# Proper Save As function in Python

Tags: python, pyqt, desktop-application

I have a default Save As function bound to a button click, that calls a modal window.
Also, I have a function, that saves needed arrays as a .xlsx file.

```
 self.data_processing.clicked.connect(self.process)


 def process(self):
    sample = pd.read_excel(self.fileName)
    list_of_index = []
    for i in range(len(sample.columns)):
        sample2 = sample.iloc[:, lambda sample: [i]]
        sample2 = sample2.columns[0]
        list_of_index.append(sample2)
    list_of_index     
    ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
    ... ... Area where all the data is computed     ... ... ...
    ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sample.xlsx')
    worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet()

    row = 0

    for col, data in enumerate(fulllist):
        worksheet1.write_column(row, col, data)
    for col, data in enumerate(fulllist_percent):
        worksheet2.write_column(row, col, data)   
    for col, data in enumerate(fulllist_click):
        worksheet3.write_column(row, col, data) 
    for col, data in enumerate(additional_info):
        worksheet4.write_column(row, col, data)

    workbook.close()
```

Basically, what I'm asking is: how to insert xlsx writer into saveFile(), so that my arrays would be saved as xlsx, using default saveAs window

My UI code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(802, 996)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.dataChoose_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.dataChoose_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.dataChoose_label.setFont(font)
        self.dataChoose_label.setObjectName("dataChoose_label")
        self.data_processing = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.data_processing.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 50, 141, 61))
        self.data_processing.setObjectName("data_processing")
        self.paramInput_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.paramInput_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 261, 21))
        self.paramInput_label.setObjectName("paramInput_label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 771, 21))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.saveSample_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.saveSample_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 271, 41))
        self.saveSample_label.setObjectName("saveSample_label")
        self.saveSample_btn = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.saveSample_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 150, 131, 41))
        self.saveSample_btn.setObjectName("saveSample_btn")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 771, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.stringInput_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.stringInput_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 260, 281, 16))
        self.stringInput_label.setObjectName("stringInput_label")
        self.stringInput_label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.stringInput_label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 270, 271, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(6)
        self.stringInput_label_2.setFont(font)
        self.stringInput_label_2.setObjectName("stringInput_label_2")
        self.stringInput_field = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.stringInput_field.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 220, 461, 121))
        self.stringInput_field.setObjectName("stringInput_field")
        self.sampleChoose_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.sampleChoose_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 410, 281, 21))
        self.sampleChoose_label.setObjectName("sampleChoose_label")
        self.sampleChoose_list = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.sampleChoose_list.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 350, 461, 151))
        self.sampleChoose_list.setObjectName("sampleChoose_list")
        self.clickSample_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.clickSample_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 580, 461, 41))
        self.clickSample_label.setObjectName("clickSample_label")
        self.clickSamle_list = QtWidgets.QColumnView(self.centralwidget)
        self.clickSamle_list.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 510, 256, 192))
        self.clickSamle_list.setObjectName("clickSamle_list")
        self.paramInput_label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.paramInput_label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 191, 16))
        self.paramInput_label_2.setObjectName("paramInput_label_2")
        self.saveClick_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.saveClick_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 790, 431, 21))
        self.saveClick_label.setObjectName("saveClick_label")
        self.saveClick_list = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.saveClick_list.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 710, 141, 191))
        self.saveClick_list.setObjectName("saveClick_list")
        self.saveClick_btn = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.saveClick_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 770, 101, 71))
        self.saveClick_btn.setObjectName("saveClick_btn")
        self.dataChooseBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.dataChooseBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 0, 151, 51))
        self.dataChooseBtn.setObjectName("dataChooseBtn")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, -10, 20, 121))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.paramInput_accept = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.paramInput_accept.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 70, 111, 41))
        self.paramInput_accept.setObjectName("paramInput_accept")
        self.paramInput_field_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.paramInput_field_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 70, 221, 31))
        self.paramInput_field_2.setObjectName("paramInput_field_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 802, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menu_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_2.setObjectName("menu_2")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.action_4 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_4.setObjectName("action_4")
        self.action_5 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_5.setObjectName("action_5")
        self.action_6 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_6.setObjectName("action_6")
        self.action_7 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_7.setObjectName("action_7")
        self.action_8 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_8.setObjectName("action_8")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_4)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_5)
        self.menu_2.addSeparator()
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_6)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_7)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_8)
        self.menu_2.addSeparator()
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_2.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.dataChoose_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите выборку для анализа:"))
        self.data_processing.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обработать"))
        self.paramInput_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Значения параметрического столбца:"))
        self.saveSample_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить файл обработанной выборки :"))
        self.saveSample_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить как..."))
        self.stringInput_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вставьте строку для анализа по выборкам:"))
        self.stringInput_label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "(помните, что размерность строки должна совпадать с размерностью выборки)"))
        self.stringInput_field.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "12.0092    16.3209    13.5649    8.2123    3.8459    2.1767    4.2975    6.0223    4.104    1.6001    1.2444    1.6035    1.0391    0.3194    0.4114    1.0386    1.4205    1.2496    0.9781    0.8515    0.7001    0.5825    0.4005    0.056    -0.0761    -0.1211    -0.5841    -0.9534    -0.5585    -0.043    0.1195    0.4775    0.8882    0.5579    -0.3917    -1.0096    -0.8487    -0.191    0.558    0.888    0.6353    0.2705    0.1206    0.0296    -0.2056    -0.3782    -0.2085    0.0363    -0.0919    -0.5511    -0.7785    -0.4769    -0.1874    -0.2101    -0.1309    -0.0181    -0.0812    0.0797    0.4885    0.5797    0.1142    -0.6158    -1.0995    -1.1537    -1.0385    -0.8175    -0.5396    -0.5002    -0.5649    -0.3875    -0.1347    -0.0554    -0.1495    -0.5774    -1.4059    -2.0242    -1.7347    -0.9614    -1.134    -2.75    -4.3387    -3.9483    -1.3619    1.0278    1.8453    2.6694    3.0748    1.6349    0.4356    0.0892    -1.9074    -3.4085    0.0632    5.6347    6.9852    2.996    -1.9341    -2.9032    -1.3316    -1.4645    -2.346    -1.8374    -0.7552    -0.1104    -0.0739    -0.2815    -0.2086    -0.0079    -0.01    23.0892    29.1765    23.5674    13.5347    6.7836    4.7064    7.4076    9.8512    7.711    4.421    3.8218    3.8774    2.4927    1.509    1.7488    2.2334    2.6185    2.666    2.4429    2.1909    1.6602    1.1591    1.0329    0.8772    0.5525    -0.0326    -0.9759    -1.4809    -1.0451    -0.5877    -0.365    0.4304    1.2717    0.8605    -0.7115    -1.9355    -1.6475    -0.4566    0.3175    0.4504    0.4514    0.3418    0.0385    -0.2063    -0.5039    -0.9804    -1.0378    -0.3791    0.1789    0.0051    -0.3564    -0.2833    0.0033    0.2184    0.3963    0.2137    -0.3378    -0.3548    0.2524    0.5642    0.4861    0.3833    0.2324    0.0401    -0.2    -0.4625    -0.6773    -0.9002    -1.0058    -0.9126    -0.7887    -0.5017    0.0166    0.089    -0.5678    -0.9103    -0.2846    0.1344    -0.6565    -1.8617    -2.8639    -3.2946    -1.7414    0.8095    1.8218    2.913    5.5284    6.8624    5.5749    2.9869    0.5648    0.1551    2.0738    3.9631    3.9425    2.2731    0.3942    -0.3964    -0.4147    -0.5376    -0.6139    -0.4817    -0.3295    -0.1489    -0.037    -0.0827    -0.1574    -0.2141    -0.2027    49.6999    69.7767    59.835    35.0647    17.4911    12.3939    17.0397    19.9471    15.007    9.2894    7.5289    6.9816    5.058    3.5523    3.8629    4.2375    3.6877    3.1812    3.0437    2.5079    1.5437    1.0561    0.9955    0.6981    0.2919    -0.2281    -1.0574    -1.3007    -0.1233    1.1392    1.1779    1.0094    1.3004    0.9836    -0.3246    -1.2542    -0.8339    0.1268    0.6459    0.6081    0.2417    -0.0669    -0.1116    -0.0771    -0.1855    -0.5842    -0.829    -0.2147    0.6164    0.5564    -0.0103    -0.2302    -0.2281    -0.2369    -0.0665    -0.042    -0.5462    -0.9621    -0.6502    0.0652    0.5529    0.5899    0.3647    0.1206    -0.0448    -0.0984    -0.0704    -0.054    -0.1167    -0.2596    -0.3558    -0.0412    0.4906    0.2146    -0.8041    -1.1069    -0.2334    0.6806    0.5641    -0.7375    -2.3345    -2.6284    -1.1741    0.2974    0.2609    -0.348    -0.4119    -0.3005    -0.2052    -0.5323    -1.2313    -0.5117    1.5922    2.7109    2.1302    0.581    -1.2169    -2.1012    -1.7068    -1.1139    -1.0359    -1.0811    -0.8442    -0.5725    -0.515    -0.4083    -0.0985    0.1166    0.0764    23.5902    34.8167    29.9879    16.4722    5.4736    2.181    6.7235    10.2094    7.094    2.9677    2.1246    2.5647    1.9333    1.0593    1.2674    1.9215    2.0104    1.6322    1.4533    1.5853    1.5679    1.3903    1.2074    0.8589    0.5309    0.274    -0.2856    -0.7007    -0.1369    0.8568    1.19    0.8973    0.617    0.3567    -0.3107    -0.9505    -0.8385    -0.1632    0.5551    1.0729    1.2167    0.6402    -0.3775    -0.9034    -0.9189    -0.9266    -0.6947    -0.1    0.1831    -0.1596    -0.5045    -0.4391    -0.5047    -0.9824    -1.1132    -0.7724    -0.583    -0.3597    0.1779    0.5606    0.1891    -0.9182    -1.8643    -2.015    -1.7303    -1.2444    -0.5691    -0.1537    -0.1987    -0.3384    -0.3042    -0.028    0.2469    -0.2079    -1.4522    -2.3573    -1.9341    -0.6466    -0.913    -4.3801    -7.9001    -6.6034    -1.4666    1.7396    2.0908    2.8658    2.1172    -1.9873    -4.8558    -5.6181    -7.1121    -5.4427    2.5583    9.8955    9.4869    2.8168    -3.7388    -4.6938    -1.7796    -0.9772    -2.3755    -2.5732    -1.3491    -0.1918    0.0832    -0.1739    -0.1287    0.1745    0.2329    10.9524    14.2529    10.6435    4.9582    1.9521    1.6169    2.798    3.7354    3.8803    4.2305    4.3    3.3745    2.361    2.0548    1.9706    1.4763    0.8167    0.3832    0.1208    -0.0447    -0.1531    -0.0436    0.3202    0.4171    -0.0697    -0.7665    -1.0122    -0.636    -0.1998    -0.1933    -0.4417    -0.5925    -0.6307    -0.5539    -0.3035    -0.0407    0.1644    0.5    1.0221    1.4231    1.3673    0.7837    -0.0852    -0.5517    -0.4074    -0.3756    -0.5013    -0.1606    0.4632    0.752    0.4683    -0.0725    -0.3727    -0.5529    -0.9097    -1.1661    -1.0929    -0.8594    -0.6232    -0.5495    -0.7225    -0.9037    -0.9698    -0.9907    -0.7276    -0.1471    0.2418    0.251    0.062    -0.255    -0.5458    -0.6746    -0.6797    -0.5133    -0.2586    -0.1598    -0.1986    -0.3142    -1.0576    -2.8278    -4.1382    -3.4232    -1.3599    1.3626    3.6212    2.6097    -0.4519    -1.445    -1.4249    -4.3882    -10.5879    -13.5279    -7.4621    3.0363    10.3816    10.2443    3.0927    -3.2072    -3.8023    -2.2997    -1.6427    -1.1828    -0.3508    0.3342    0.4442    0.3325    0.5332    0.924    0.8647    20.8696    27.1891    21.6745    11.839    6.2656    5.5586    7.4727    8.2034    6.8261    5.9256    5.8057    5.0093    3.6226    2.7789    2.5921    2.29    1.7347    1.2871    0.9973    0.7089    0.361    0.3081    0.6116    0.5802    -0.1118    -0.9791    -1.3397    -0.8983    -0.1141    0.0817    -0.3459    -0.3375    0.32    0.6936    0.3626    -0.1519    -0.2493    0.063    0.3576    0.4193    0.4442    0.457    0.1041    -0.4185    -0.5981    -0.6161    -0.6173    -0.2822    0.3205    0.7469    0.681    0.1792    -0.2842    -0.4016    -0.3742    -0.4325    -0.5638    -0.5962    -0.4603    -0.4061    -0.4795    -0.3646    -0.2065    -0.3974    -0.5597    -0.2419    0.1404    0.1841    0.0232    -0.1716    -0.3105    -0.388    -0.3489    -0.1462    0.0227    0.0825    0.0584    -0.1485    -0.6376    -1.44    -1.9336    -1.2505    0.2067    1.7441    2.735    1.8703    0.396    0.5912    1.1902    0.4427    -2.003    -4.3035    -3.2353    -0.1565    1.6481    1.7801    0.4805    -1.2714    -1.8955    -1.4548    -0.8987    -0.5058    -0.0902    0.2493    0.3019    0.2254    0.3217    0.5682    0.6039    44.7774    59.2644    48.3444    25.6805    12.7331    11.518    15.1719    15.6678    12.5041    11.6583    12.2632    10.3639    7.2073    5.7946    5.786    4.9055    3.2123    2.2999    1.9652    1.327    0.6183    0.6235    1.2602    1.5138    0.9206    -0.1558    -0.8477    -0.4624    0.4653    0.8362    0.5566    0.5153    1.1414    1.6521    1.2413    0.3184    -0.3617    -0.5259    -0.173    0.1837    0.166    0.1927    0.4739    0.8132    0.9718    0.5724    -0.0814    -0.2193    -0.0169    0.0211    -0.0229    -0.1343    -0.3588    -0.3259    0.1188    0.4219    -0.0175    -0.8971    -1.2925    -1.0202    -0.6154    -0.3013    -0.1924    -0.4746    -0.692    -0.3546    0.137    0.3454    0.1956    -0.3318    -0.7643    -0.6234    -0.2666    -0.3225    -0.7777    -0.9072    -0.3201    0.4168    0.3082    -0.8645    -1.542    -0.3366    1.5401    2.4102    2.1885    0.7324    -1.6746    -3.6351    -4.4016    -4.5757    -5.476    -5.747    -3.0459    0.9132    4.0289    5.1989    3.2462    0.3871    -0.5417    -0.1191    0.2969    0.4394    0.3879    0.1941    -0.0016    0.0158    0.3095    0.5857    0.411    30.2006    39.3582    29.9576    14.0813    7.3008    9.0822    11.8449    10.5825    7.8682    8.9961    10.9417    9.5758    7.2909    6.7268    6.7451    5.2366    2.8996    1.7664    1.6456    1.4861    1.26    1.5259    2.0742    1.9703    1.1513    0.1103    -0.4006    0.073    0.5807    0.3707    -0.1779    -0.656    -0.6826    -0.0756    0.6797    1.0599    0.9552    0.737    0.7427    0.4973    -0.218    -0.7341    -0.6726    -0.1082    0.4481    0.0778    -0.9304    -1.3084    -0.9726    -0.6918    -0.7392    -0.9288    -0.9103    -0.6299    -0.6061    -1.0453    -1.4129    -1.3664    -1.1234    -0.9574    -0.9611    -1.0098    -1.0153    -0.9935    -0.6263    0.0147    0.1319    -0.3184    -0.7648    -1.0499    -0.9592    -0.593    -0.5487    -0.7664    -0.8247    -0.5693    0.2136    1.3327    1.0359    -1.7183    -3.9489    -3.0081    -0.4778    2.0716    4.0662    3.2434    -1.292    -6.2305    -8.7793    -12.8573    -21.6219    -23.7086    -9.6675    9.8865    22.0893    20.9908    8.476    -1.5682    -2.1344    -0.4314    -0.8335    -1.3351    -0.7732    -0.0697    0.0553    0.1637    0.8374    1.4351    1.0663"))
        self.sampleChoose_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбери выборку(-ки) для анализа строки:"))
        self.clickSample_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Значения суммарных весовых откликов и степени валидности строки:"))
        self.paramInput_label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "для определения корреляций"))
        self.saveClick_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранение данных по проверямой строке в выбранной выборке:"))
        self.saveClick_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить как..."))
        self.dataChooseBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите файл..."))
        self.paramInput_accept.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подтвердить"))
        self.paramInput_field_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 250.0, 300.0, 350.0, 400.0, 450.0, 500.0, 550.0, 600.0, 650.0, 700.0, 750.0, 800.0, 850.0, 900.0, 950.0, 1000.0, 1100.0, 1150.0, 1200.0, 1250.0, 1300.0, 1350.0, 1400.0, 1450.0, 1500.0, 1550.0, 1600.0, 1650.0, 1700.0, 1750.0, 1800.0, 1850.0, 1900.0, 1950.0, 2000.0, 2050.0, 2100.0, 2150.0, 2200.0, 2250.0, 2300.0, 2350.0, 2400.0, 2450.0, 2500.0, 2550.0, 2600.0, 2650.0, 2700.0, 2750.0, 2800.0, 2850.0, 2900.0, 2950.0, 3000.0"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Файл"))
        self.menu_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Правка"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Открыть..."))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить..."))
        self.action_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Печать"))
        self.action_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Отменить"))
        self.action_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Копировать"))
        self.action_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вырезать"))
        self.action_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вставить"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My main program

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import scipy.stats
import xlsxwriter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, qApp, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent, QObject
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        qApp.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.dataChooseBtn.clicked.connect(self.selectFile)
        self.saveClick_btn.clicked.connect(self.saveFile)

        self.saveSample_btn.clicked.connect(self.saveSample)

        self.paramInput_accept.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.data_processing.clicked.connect(self.process)
        self.show()





    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
                self.close()
        return super(MyMainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def accept(self):
        textboxValue = self.paramInput_field_2.text()
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', "Значения параметрического столбца: " + textboxValue, QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)



    def selectFile(self):
        self.fileName = None
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выберите стандартизированную выборку", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)
            self.fileName = fileName





    def process(self):
        sample = pd.read_excel(self.fileName)
        list_of_index = []
        for i in range(len(sample.columns)):
            sample2 = sample.iloc[:, lambda sample: [i]]
            sample2 = sample2.columns[0]
            list_of_index.append(sample2)
        list_of_index   

        fulllist = []
        for i in list_of_index:
            sample3 = sample[i].tolist()
            fulllist.append(sample3)

        fulllist_percent = []
        column_percent = []
        len(fulllist)
        for i in range(len(fulllist)):
            for j in range(len(fulllist[i])):
                percent_rank = scipy.stats.percentileofscore(fulllist[i], fulllist[i][j])
                column_percent.append(percent_rank)
            fulllist_percent.append(column_percent)
            column_percent = []

        fulllist_rank = []
        for i in range(len(fulllist)):
            rank = len(fulllist[i]) - scipy.stats.rankdata(fulllist[i]) + 1
            fulllist_rank.append(rank)

        param = self.paramInput_field_2.text()    
        param = [float(i) for i in param.split(',')]
        param_rank = scipy.stats.rankdata(param).astype(int)


        column_corr = []
        for i in range(len(fulllist)):
            correlation = scipy.stats.spearmanr(param_rank[::-1], fulllist_rank[i])
            column_corr.append(correlation[0])



        fulllist_click = []
        for j in range (len(fulllist_percent)):
            middle = []
            if column_corr[j] > 0:
                for i in range(len(fulllist_percent[j])):
                    solve = column_corr[j] * fulllist_percent[j][i]
                    middle.append(solve)
            else:
                for i in range (len(fulllist_percent[j])):    
                    solve = abs(column_corr[j]) * (100 - fulllist_percent[j][i])
                    middle.append(solve)
            fulllist_click.append(middle)

        list_of_rowsumm = []
        rowsumm = 0
        fulllist_clickT = numpy.asarray(fulllist_click).T.tolist()

        for i in range(len(fulllist_clickT)):
            rowsumm = sum(fulllist_clickT[i])
            list_of_rowsumm.append(rowsumm)

        percent_rowsumm = []
        for i in list_of_rowsumm:
            x = scipy.stats.percentileofscore(list_of_rowsumm, i)
            percent_rowsumm.append(x)

        additional_info = []
        additional_info.append(list_of_rowsumm)
        additional_info.append(percent_rowsumm)

        self.fulllist = fulllist
        self.fulllist_percent = fulllist_percent
        self.fulllist_click = fulllist_click
        self.additional_info = additional_info


        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sample.xlsx')
        worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet()

        row = 0

        for col, data in enumerate(fulllist):
            worksheet1.write_column(row, col, data)
        for col, data in enumerate(fulllist_percent):
            worksheet2.write_column(row, col, data)   
        for col, data in enumerate(fulllist_click):
            worksheet3.write_column(row, col, data) 
        for col, data in enumerate(additional_info):
            worksheet4.write_column(row, col, data)

        workbook.close()


#         return self.fulllist, self.fulllist_percent, self.fulllist_click, self.additional_info



    def saveSample(self):


        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileNameSave, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()","","Excel files (*.xlsx)", options=options)
        return fileNameSave
        print(fileNameSave)

        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook()
        worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet()

        row = 0

        for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist):
            worksheet1.write_column(row, col, data)
        for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist_percent):
            worksheet2.write_column(row, col, data)   
        for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist_click):
            worksheet3.write_column(row, col, data) 
        for col, data in enumerate(self.additional_info):
            worksheet4.write_column(row, col, data)

        workbook.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The question is quite unclear. I don't see what's the link between your 2 functions. Could you explain more what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @Yohboy after processing the data, it is saved using xlsx writer. It is being saved in the current directory, with the preset name "Sample.xlsx". What I'm trying to do, is to resave this file with another name, without deleting the initial one, using modal window caused by SaveFile() function

Comment: @Yohboy or at least to combine xlsx writer with saveas function. So that all the processes are automatized

Comment: what's the purpose of the arg `fileName` in `process(self, fileName)` ? Why using `file = self.fileName` instead of directly uses `self.fileName` ? In this case, what is self.fileName ?

Comment: @Yohboy edited this part, for the more organic view. I was testing different syntax constructions and did not edit it back. `self.fileName` is the name of input file to process

Comment: @Yohboy basically, what I'm asking is: how to insert xlsx writer into saveFile(), so that my arrays would be saved as xlsx, using default saveas window

Comment: So fileName and *.xlsx are different right ? Basically you open fileName, process it, then save it in sample.xlsx ?

Comment: @Yohboy exactly.

Comment: And what is the idea behind the save as ?

Comment: @Yohboy the idea is to
1. process input data, get a number of arrays, that are written into different sheets of xlsx document
2. save it as a new file, with custom name and dir ( I may need it for further processing computations).

Comment: @Yohboy and `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sample.xlsx')` is not fitting for me, cause it should be kind of "user-frendly", so i'm trying to in-build this array-to-xlsx into saveFile() func

Comment: You need to replace sample.xlsx with your custom name (in your custom dir). You can choose a custom name and dir with your modal window, and store those custom in your class attribute so you will be able to reuse it. i don't know if I'm clear, but I can't provide an example if I don't have a minimal code to run in local.

Comment: Now I see, thanks. The last question is: where are those custom dir and name are stored?

Comment: you store them where you want, best is to store it as class attribute, then once set, you will be able to use them in all your class

Comment: @Yohboy but I mean, when I choose the dir and type the name how can I call this "output" information for my xlsxwritter. `print(fileNameSave)` is not working for some reason

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code that run your application ? (without the processing etc ...)

Comment: @Yohboy wasn't sure what is required, so posted the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming getSaveFileName returning you the good value, I think you just need to change your function `saveSample(self)` by :

```
def saveSample(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileNameSave, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()","","Excel files (*.xlsx)", options=options)
    print(fileNameSave)
    self.fileNameSave = fileNameSave
    self.callNewFunc()
```

where callNewFunc is :

```
 def callNewFunc(self):
    if self.fileNameSave:
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(self.fileNameSave)
        worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet()

        row = 0

        for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist):
            worksheet1.write_column(row, col, data)
        for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist_percent):
            worksheet2.write_column(row, col, data)   
        for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist_click):
            worksheet3.write_column(row, col, data) 
        for col, data in enumerate(self.additional_info):
            worksheet4.write_column(row, col, data)

        workbook.close()
```

You can call this function from `process` too. You need to set `fileNameSave` before using it. And set it in **init** method : `self.fileNameSave = None`
Be sure `self.fileNameSave` is correct before you call `callNewFunc`.

Does it help ?

Comment: It helped! Also added `self.fileNameSave+".xlsx"` for xlsxwritter to save properly, thanks

Comment: Great, better to store `.xlsx` directly in `self.fileNameSave` no ?